# How to interpret the next sentence: 日本の新しい大学を見学します。

Tags: grammar

I was told in class that

> 日本の新しい大学を見学します。
>   *Nihon no atarashī daigaku o kengaku shimasu.*

means

> I will visit a new university in Japan.

I understand this as

> I am visiting the new Japanese university (right now).

I don't see the context to think this action will happen later, and besides it has the ~します ending.

Where is the "will" part?

Comment: @KawaUso Please avoid posting answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Japanese doesn't have a clear distinction between present tense and future tense, and there is no simple equivalent of English 'will'. A sentence like 大学を見学します usually means "I *will* visit ...". There are several other ways to express your intention or plan, including [つもり](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A-tsumori/).

Japanese does have a distinction between simple present form and progressive form (i.e, "I visit" vs "I am visiting"). If you are currently visiting the university, you have to say 大学を見学しています. You can learn this teiru-form [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-te-iru/), for example.